# How to reduce response time for first request

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Work on Asp.net mvc5 **Code-First** EF-6. My application data model is large enough so **ObjectContext** has so many classes that is required to access the database then processing the classes may delay the web application response to the first request for a page.What to do? how to increase application response?

Note:So far I know When application first time create the object of ObjectContext,the entity framework work on a set of classes that is required to access the database. In this situation if your data model is large then creating the classes may delay the web application response to the first request for a page. Want to know how to reduce this response.

Comment: "may delay" or "does delay"?  Have you proven that it is actually a problem before you try and solve it?  You know that a context doesn't load all of the data from the model into it, right?

Answer (score 0):

When EF starts up, it will run your database initializer. You can get a bit of a speed boost if you remove that initializer which by default is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext>`

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContextType>(null); //System.Data.Entity namespace
```

Generally people place that in the Global.asax or the static constructor of the `DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would keep any start up logic in `Application_Start` event in `Global.asax` file. BUT this will not fire until first user visits, and if you are doing some heavy processing, which takes a lot of time, it could become very frustrating for the first user.

To overcome this situation, you can configure your application to auto start and execute pre load logic.

For this you need to create a class that implements `IProcessHostPreloadClient` interface, and write your initialization logic in it -

```
    public class ApplicationPreload : System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostPreloadClient 
    {
        public void Preload(string[] parameters) 
        {
                // Write initialization and loading logic here
         }
    }
```

Next you need to register the information about this in `applicationHost.config` (*C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config*) by adding a `startMode="AlwaysRunning"` attribute to the appropriate `<applicationPools>` -

```
<applicationPools>
     <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>
```

In the same file register the auto start provider -

```
<!-- Just AFTER closing the `sites` element AND AFTER `webLimits` tag -->
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
    <add name="ApplicationPreload" type="WebApplication1.ApplicationPreload, WebApplication1" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

and last, in `<Sites>`, locate your site and specify the provider -

```
<sites>
    <site name="MySite" id="1">
        <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"
                              serviceAutoStartProvider="ApplicationPreload" />
    </site>
</sites>
```

If you do not like to make changes to `applicationHost.config`, you can also do these changes through IIS.

More details can be found here- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Having said that, you should also attempt to minimize the amount of data required at startup, and load just relevant contextual data, if your design permits.